# Python socket threading with kbhit

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, keypress

I've run out of idea with how can msvcrt.kbhit() in python can print out the data as soon as I clicked the specified key need to pressed. It looks like that while loop needs to loop once more before it can print out my desire output. Can someone please help me. Here's my code:

```
def run(self):
    global state
    print "\nClient connection received!\n"
    self.channel.send("Status: Server connection received")
    while 1:
        ctr = 1
        while 1:
            self.clientmess = self.channel.recv(Buffer)
            if msvcrt.kbhit():
                if msvcrt.getch() == 's':
                    print "stop"
                    break
    #the codes belo is what i will want for self.clientmess will be so its not necessary I think to put
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: when the code recieve data from a client and I press 's' key on the keyboard the print stop dont print as I press the key, it needs another data to recieve before the print "stop" to be printted in the screen

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time your program blocks in the `recv` call so until some data is received it will not execute `kbhit`+`getch`. If you need to handle keyboard input immediately you probably need to make the socket non-blocking and poll both the socket and the keyboard in the loop, handling data from them as it appears.